# Using $.get with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the Jquery builtin validator on my page.  The issue is that I have certain fields that only are required if the JobID (entered into another field) does not already exist in our database.  I have a simple service which simply takes JobID and returns True or False based on whether the JobID exists, but I can't seem to get this information where I want it.  Some sample code:

```
$("#dep_form").validate({
        rules: {
            JobID: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            OrgName: {
                required: function(element) { //This field is required if the JobID is new.
                    return $("#jobinfo").html().length==15; }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            JobID: {
                required: "Enter a Job Number.",
                digits: "Only numbers are allowed in Job ID's.",
                minlength: "Job Number must be at least 3 digits"
            },
            OrgName: {
                required: "Select a Practice from the dropdown list."
            }
        },
        errorClass: "ui-state-error-input",
    errorLabelContainer: "#errorbox",
    errorElement: 'li',
    errorContainer: "#validation_errors",
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    focusinvalid: false
};
```

Currently, I'm using a lazy method to validate (shown above).  However, I now have access to a service using the URL:

```
var lookupurl = "/deposits/jobidvalidate/?q=" + $("#id_JobID").val() + "&t=" + new Date().getTime();
```

which is a page which will contain just the word True or False based on whether that given JobID exists.  I've tried half a dozen different ways of setting variables and calling functions within functions and still cannot get a way to simply return the value of that page (which I've been trying to access with $.get() ) to my validator, so that required is set to true when the Job does not exist and false if the job already exists.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using an asynchronous Ajax request (the `$.get`). My guess is your code looks something like this:

```
var result;

$.ajax({
    url: lookupurl,
    success: function() { result = /* parse the response here */; },
    dataType: 'html'
});

return result;
```

But this won't work because `result` will be returned before the `success` callback has fired (and in doing so, set the value of `result`). If my guess is right, then you need to make your `$get` synchronous, but you do have to use `$.ajax` to do so.

**Edit @Pointy:** `$.get` is, according to [the API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), shorthand for

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

...which is, by default, asynchronous.

Comment: I think that `$.get()` is always synchronous.

Comment: That description (that I am getting result returned BEFORE the callback fires) is exactly the problem.  I guess now it seems pretty obvious, I will try using $.ajax instead of $.get and specifying async:false.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem! If you found my answer helpful, feel free to upvote and/or accept it. That way, people will know that your question has been answered, and which answer is the correct one.

Comment: I was just testing it out to make sure I could make it work.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get at the result of the "get" as a parameter to the callback you pass it.

```
var jobIdExists;
$.get(url, function(data) { jobIdExists = data =="True"; });
```

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a sync/async problem.  I was able to solve it by using:

```
var lookupurl = "/deposits/jobidvalidate/?q=" + $("#id_JobID").val() + "&t=" + new Date().getTime();
var result;
$.ajax({
    url: lookupurl,
    success: function(data) { result = data;},
    dataType: 'html',
    async: false
});
return result;
```